# Error regarding \contentsline when compiling

Tags: table-of-contents, errors

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline{subsection}{\numberline{}Something}{13}}

\end{document}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error message:

```
! Argument of \contentsline has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.9 ...ne{subsection}{\numberline{}Something}{13}}
```

The error message is very clear but I have no idea where the extra `}` is. How do I resolve the issue?

P.S. I've taken the idea from frabjous' answer at https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=10082.

Comment: Without deeper considerations: do you actually write "{\numberline{}Something}"?

Comment: You need an extra argument for `\contentsline` because of `hyperref` and some `\protect`s.

Comment: From the duplicate: `\phantomsection
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{subsection} 
{\protect\numberline{}Something}{13}{}}` works in your MWE.

Comment: contentsline now takes always 4 arguments.

Comment: Thanks alot, all of you. If one of you writes an answer, I will then accept it.